GMAIL mails providing messageId with special characters not able to search query IMAP
I am trying use IMAP to fetch mails send by GMAIL. But the problem which I am facing is when I am trying to pass the command through which I can fetch mails from IMAP it is giving response count 0 as the incoming messageId from GMAIL includes some special characters due to which my IMAP is not returning any mail as it is not recognising the messageId.
So what I am stuck on is I want to somehow pass the entire messageId with special character (=, + particularly in my case) to be passed and fetch me a result.
Example message ID from GMAIL which are not working due to + or = -
<CAFUuS3vuQ1VfbQck=t_DEZA-mGkxcOBkpb8SdntDGqHMAu5ZQw@mail.gmail.com>
<CAFUuS3vuQ1VfbQck+t_DEZA-mGkxcOBkpb8SdntDGqHMAu5ZQw@mail.gmail.com>

Working IDs -
<CAFUuS3vuQ1VfbQckt_DEZA-mGkxcOBkpb8SdntDGqHMAu5ZQw@mail.gmail.com>
Code which I am using to fetch the mail -
const searchQuery = [["HEADER", "Message-ID",  messageId]];

Module used  - NODE-IMAP
NOTE - I also verified that the mail exists with these messageId as they can be seen while fetching all mails. But the case particularly holds back in case of search query.
I tried to pass it with "\" so that somehow it can recognise it. I also tried UTF-8 conversion and  URL encode and decode.

Sounds like a server bug. You might be able to work around it using a substring search, e.g. searching for the prefix of the message-id until the first character that triggers the server bug. But do report this as a server bug.
